# Can't connect to a server program on my PC outside local network with Python socket module

Tags: python, python-3.x, server

so I'm trying to connect to my home computer which is running a server script in Python.
In the client program I used my server PC's IpV4 address to try to connect to it.
I'm trying to connect with 2 instances of the client program that are both connected to a different WiFi router than the server.
Server program code:

```
from socket import *
while True:
    print("Connecting")
    s = socket()
    f = socket()
    s.bind((gethostname(), 10000))

    s.listen(2)

    c, a = s.accept()
    print("1st client connected")
    x, v = s.accept()
    print("2nd client connected")
    print('Both clients connected')
    while True:
        try:
            p = c.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            p2 = x.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            print(p)
            print(p2)
            c.send(p2.encode("utf-8"))
            x.send(p.encode("utf-8"))
        except ConnectionResetError:
            break
    s.close()
    c.close()
    print("Clients disconected")
```

Client code (am I using the correct Ip?):

```
from socket import *
s = socket()
s.connect(("192.168.1.12", 10000))
```

Then after some code:

```
s.send(str(self.pos()).encode("utf-8"))
```

Then after more code:

```
self.pe = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
```

How can I get this to work outside a local network?

Comment: Welcome to the world of networking! The concept of having separate local networks communicating together is called *routing*. That means that your problem cannot be solved at program level, but you must configure a route between the 2 networks. Once this is done, the program will work tranparently. Said differently, the question is off topic here because it is not a programming problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about general networking and not about programming. Yet it would not be suited for Server Fault (too general).